# How to do a cut in the middle of the polygon on Altium Designer 19?

Tags: altium, split, polygon

I'm wondering how to do a cut in the middle of the polygon using the Altium. It seems it has the tools just for making the cutouts and splitting the planes, but not making the cuttlines in the middle of the plane. Tried various methods to achieve this, but unsuccessfully. It would be great if someone could explain how this could be done. Thanks!

[image: cutline in the polygon]

Btw this is just an example what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You can draw a *line* in the polygon and it will do what you need (it certainly did in 17 and 18).

Comment: @PeterSmith it works, but what to do with that line? because if I remove the line and repour the polygon, the cutline disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically draw a line, select it and go to Tools -> Convert -> Create Cutout from Selected Primitives and repour the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a polygon into two by selecting it, then using `Place` >> `Slice Polygon Pour`, draw a dividing line and acknowledge that you actually want to slice the polygon.

You can find it in the [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-PolygonPour((Polygon+Pour))_AD#PolygonPour-SlicePolygonPour).

Comment: I know how to split the polygon into two, but I don't want to.. I need a cutline inside the polygon... updated the question with a picture what I'm trying to achieve